# Should I switch to AngularJS? (Angular vs Jquery)

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am developing a web application using HTML Canvas. It involves just some simple manipulation of images based on values from GET/POST calls. I have not worked with Angular JS before and have written the app pretty much using Jquery and AJAX. I was wondering if I should switch to Angular JS? Is it suitable for this application? Is it worth spending time to learn it and modify the application? I am open to learn about other frameworks too which would be ideal for this use-case.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you should learn Angular , as my personal opinion Angular is a framework that help you to maintain your code clear. It's a tool that makes the common task easier and quickly. Also you can use both in your project.

Comment: You can't beat [this Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/) for learning,. It's the most upvoted, for good reason. Although titled Angular 2, he keeps it updated. I just used it to learn Angular 12. I want to buy all of Max's courses, this on is so good